# Line Chart Display Problem in Python Colab?

Tags: python, matplotlib, google-colaboratory

The below code called and merged two different csv files based on dates. Although data preparation has done properly, plot shows a wrong result. Does anyone has idea?

[image]

code link: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/131hMZ0oNmbC_ygR-ppTaiGoVrzG9JmXd?usp=sharing

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from google.colab import files
data = files.upload()
insitu = files.upload()

from pandas.io import excel
import io
df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(data['lakeEl.csv']))
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.set_index('date', inplace = True)

df2 = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(insitu['waterLevel.csv']))
df2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date'])
df2.set_index('date', inplace = True)


merg = pd.merge(df, df2, how = 'outer', on = 'date')
lake_level = merg.dropna()


import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
ax.plot(lake_level['area']);
```

Comment: Your data are strings.

Comment: I tried by astype function but still doesn't work.

Comment: As I checked it is float64.